# Box2dLights on libGDX android project

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx, buildpath

I tried to import the jars of Box2dLights to my project in libgdx, I configure the Buildpath and errors always happen.
Where I need to put the jars? Someone know please?
thanks : )

Comment: Please include the error messages you are seeing, and your current buildpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click into your core libGDX project, Build Path > Configure Built Path...

Select the Libraries tab, Add JARs... and choose box2dlights.jar you've downloaded. Then on the same tab select it and click on the Source attachment. Click on Edit... and browse your box2dlights-sources.jar

//important part

Now, right-click on your libGDX android project, Build Path > Configure Built Path... and do the same as later, but choose your box2dlights.jar located in your core project.

Go on Order and Export tab, check your box2dlights.jar, and move it up, below your gdx-backend-android.jar

still trying to improve my english,
Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter.

Put the Jar in the libs's folder of your android project

**When you configure the Buildpath**, in the **Order and export**, don't forget to **check** the box2dlights.jar

By the way, if you still got errors, you should tell us what are them.